How put bypass the local connection with the ChromeWebDriver if I haven't the IP but only an url?
I am learning test automation following a tutorial on the site TAU by applitools. I am using IntelliJ community edtion as IDE.
I have to practice with TestNG so I followed the instruction writing a similar code to open a website for practice:
package com.testautomationu.chp3annotations.Configuration;

//Class to exercise in testing using the BeforeMethod and AfterMethod notation

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    
    public class BM_AM_OrangeHRM {
        WebDriver driver;
    
        @BeforeMethod
        public void setUp() {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps", "");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Carlo Cumino\\Downloads\\Drivers\\chromedriver-win64" +
                    "\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver= new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/");
        }
    
        @Test
        public void signIn(){
            WebElement textUser= driver.findElement(By.id("txtUsername"));
            textUser.sendKeys("Admin");
    
            WebElement textPassowrd= driver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword"));
            textPassowrd.sendKeys("Admin123");
    
            WebElement buttonLogin = driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin"));
            buttonLogin.click();
    
        }
    
        @AfterMethod
        public void tearDown(){
            driver.quit();
        }

The problem is that even I use a "rigth" version of chromedriver (both my browser and the driver are 130.0.****) on the console I have this response
Starting ChromeDriver 131.0.6778.24 (970493e0d1f268b99c3e386d3bd2ee99719089d3-refs/branch-heads/6778@{#1222}) on port 19181
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully on port 19181.
nov 04, 2024 4:57:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$1 call
INFO: Polling http://localhost:19181/healthz
nov 04, 2024 4:57:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$1 call
INFO: Polling http://localhost:19181/healthz
nov 04, 2024 4:57:37 PM org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$1 call
INFO: Polling http://localhost:19181/healthz 

Which endend with this runtime exception:
INFO: Polling http://localhost:19181/healthz

java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out waiting for http://localhost:19181/healthz to be available after 20058 ms

Now I am going to expose my problem: I know that Chrome have the "Ip White List" but in the code from the exercise they are given me only a web address not the IP of the site.
How can I resolve it?
Note: I don't know if is connected but the selenium library of chromedriver that I have downloaded have not the comand to manage and open windows.

that system property ""webdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps" is no longer supported so you can remove that.  The tutorial is probably pretty out-dated if it includes that.   Worth noting that you seem to be running version 131 of the chromedriver ("Starting ChromeDriver 131.0.6778.24" is shown) so maybe that's the issue?  the --allowed-ips flag is for remote connections to the driver methinks... so that only certain remote clients can run tests.  By default it only allows local connections.

So chromedriver runs a server on localhost, but it looks like it's having trouble connecting to it.  (something blocking localhost connections? maybe the deprecated whitelistIP call with none whitelisted?)

@browsermator After the 131 I have tried also with the 130 but wihit the same result. Yes I've to admit that the tutorial is a little old, but I am strating from the basic so I don't understand why the more basic function must be frobidden for me. More over, I have just install chromedriver on this pc (my work pc) that day. I am learning how testing, so I don't know very well as an enegeneer.

@browsermator I have re-tried with a 130 version of chrome driver but same result Starting ChromeDriver 130.0.6723.91 (53ac076783696778ecc8f360ea31765c29c240ad-refs/branch-heads/6723@{#1517}) on port 32653 Only local connections are allowed.

The "only local connections are allowed" message is normal.  Are you also seeing a timeout exception?  Did you remove the whitelistIP bit?  You might also try setting ChromeOptions, with  options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*"); set.

If you are using the latest version of Selenium, then you don't need to be downloading chromedriver and making it available locally and setting the location of it via the System.setProperty(). Selenium now takes care of doing all that for you. You should also get rid of this line System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Carlo Cumino\\Downloads\\Drivers\\chromedriver-win64" +                     "\\chromedriver.exe");

maybe not, but I tried without TsetNG and I open the windows even the system gives me Error 403 (and yes, I've set the options to allow all. I don't know if it could be the sophos antivirus)
